# Form binding in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have the following domain classes in my app

```
class Video {
    private Image image;
}

class Image {
    private final Map<ImageType, ImageAsset> images 
}

class ImageAsset {
    Url href;
}

enum ImageType {
   S1, S2, S3;
}
```

So basically a Video has 1 Image which has N ImageAssets - which are mapped by ImageType.

In my Spring MVC form - I bind it to the Video object in the Model:

```
<form:form commandName="video">
```

One of the fields of the form needs to be bound to the href field of a given ImageAsset. I would have expected to do it thus:

```
<form:imput path="image.images[S1].href" />
```

but this returns the error:

```
Invalid property 'image.images[S1].href' of bean class [Image]
```

removing the "href" from the expression returns something - I think its an ImageAsset, but I cannot access anymore properties form there.

How do I bind this form field to the href property of ImageAsset?

Thanks -

Comment: Whoops - turns out the answer was far simpler than I had expected.

ImageAsset didn't conform to the JavaBean spec.

Sorted!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Avja Zelur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214971/avja-zelur) found solution [himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320177/form-binding-in-spring-mvc#comment11760677_9320177):

ImageAsset didn't conform to the JavaBean spec. Sorted!